# Error instantiating class: 'org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.KStemFilterFactory

Tags: solr

My solrconfig.xml worked fine in SOLR 4.1 but when I upgraded SOLR to 4.5.1, I started getting the following error:

```
Error instantiating class: 'org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.KStemFilterFactory'
```

Any idea what went wrong? I can still see the same class exists in 4.5.1 so I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

you need lucene-analyzers-common-4.5.1.jar in the relevant folder (as given by sharedLib="lib" in solr.xml if you are using that) or otherwise explicitly include it in solrconfig.xml